# convert "AWS::Lambda::Function" to "AWS::Serverless::Function"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, aws-lambda-edge

I want to use code in file, but only inline code can be used in "AWS::Lambda::Function" template, can I convert "AWS::Lambda::Function" template to "AWS::Serverless::Function" template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documenation clearly shows that the standard Lambda Function resource can take inline code but also a reference to a S3 location: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html

Inline code is anyway only recommended for simple just a few line lambda’s.

For pipelining it is makes deployment easy with `aws cloudformation package` CLI command. It will take the lambda code upload it to a bucket and referend the correct artifact for you inside the template, which then is ready for deployment!

I known it is not a 100% answer to you quesion, but eventually you can reconsider if you really need to convert it!